# ¿Cómo hacer update a una tabla con dos condiciones diferentes en SQL?

Tags: sql

no se si es posible realizar lo que quiero hacer, pero no encuentro informacion al respecto

Tengo un procedimiento que realiza lo siguiente

```
UPDATE ctl_cfdipagosropa SET des_concepto = 'Factura ' + @UUIDnuevo WHERE des_foliofiscal = @UUIDviejo 
AND imp_factura > 0

UPDATE ctl_cfdipagosropa SET des_foliofiscal = @UUIDnuevo WHERE des_foliofiscal = @UUIDviejo
```

Quisiera poder hacer ambos updates en uno solo, es esto posible? he intentado de varias maneras pero no puedo, este fue mi intento:

```
UPDATE ctl_cfdipagosropa SET des_concepto = 'Factura ' + @UUIDnuevo WHERE des_foliofiscal = @UUIDviejo 
AND imp_factura > 0, des_foliofiscal = @UUIDnuevo WHERE des_foliofiscal = @UUIDviejo
```

Comment: "No puedo" que significa? Algún error? Los errores se ponen en la pregunta. Por ahora: esa sintaxis es inválida. Hay UN SOLO where con uno o más AND para filtrar el conjunto sobre el que aplicas el UPDATE. No existe esa sintaxis que buscas

Answer (score 1):

Lo que intentas no se puede hacer, por que solo puedes aplicar un WHERE a tu consulta.

Yo como lo resolvería seria de la siguiente manera.

```
UPDATE ctl_cfdipagosropa 
SET
    des_concepto = CASE WHEN imp_factura > 0 THEN 'Factura ' + @UUIDnuevo ELSE des_concepto END,
    des_foliofiscal = @UUIDnuevo
WHERE des_foliofiscal = @UUIDviejo
```

Aplico los dos updates en la misma consulta, solo valido en el primero si imp_factura  es mayor a 0 y lo actualizo, de lo contrario que siga con su mismo valor.